# Randomly sampling numerals from a list whose aggregate needs to be at least greater than a given benchmark

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, random

I have a list of tuples formed by 1000 object ids and their scores, i.e.:

`scored_items = [('14',534.9),('4',86.0),('78',543.21),....]`.

Let `T` be the aggregated score of the top 20 highest scoring items.

That's easy. Using python:

`top_20 = sorted(score_items, key=lambda k: k[1],reverse = True)[:20]
T = sum(n for _, n in top_20)`

Next, let `t` equal a quarter of `T`. I.e. in python: `t = math.ceil(T/4)`

**My question is**: what's the most efficient way to randomly select 20 items (without replacement) from `scored_items` such that their aggregated score is equal to or greater than (but never lower than) `t`? They may or may not include items from `top_20`.

Would prefer an answer in Python, and would prefer to not rely on external libraries much

---

**Background:** This is an item-ranking algorithm that is *strategy proof* according to an esoteric - but useful - Game Theory theorem. Source: section 2.5 in [this](http://www.arpitaghosh.com/papers/games_hcomp.pdf) paper, or just read footnote `18` on page 11 of this same link. Btw *strategy proof* essentially means it's tough to game it.

I'm a neophyte python programmer and have been mulling how to solve this problem for a while now, but just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Would be great to know how the experts would approach and solve this.

I suppose the most simplistic (and least performant perhaps) way is to keep randomly generating sets of 20 items till their scores' sum exceeds or equals `t`.

But there has to be a better way to do this right?

Comment: Python has a `random.sample()` function that could be helpful. If you want a truly random sample I can't think of a way that would be better than calling it repeatedly until you get the desired sum. Your criteria at least guarantees such a subset exists so it wouldn't run forever

Comment: Sounds iffy you want to select random elements that meet a criteria. will you be doing this more than once? and is `T` *static*? does it change between selections?

Comment: @wwii: yes, I'll be frequently calling this to rank some objects. `T` would be different (and indeed the list of items would have partially changed) each time this is called.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin: Something tells me this same economist can probably prove it's possible our `random.sample()` approach can run forever! But I guess in practice, I can impose a hard bound on it. That's a bummer though. I kept thinking I was missing an obvious solution here. Guess economists finally wrote something programmers couldn't efficiently recreate.

Comment: @HassanBaig do you want the values to be uniformly selected? I can see a more efficient solution using weighted random samples.

Comment: @pault: could you elaborate?

Comment: Weight samples in such a way that higher scoring samples are more likely to be chosen. For more "randomness" you can do the selections iteratively such that the weights vary based on how close you are to the target threshold. You may still have to repeat the sampling until you get a valid collection, but it should converge faster. If you could include an example of your data, I could try to elaborate with some code.

Comment: @pault: sounds like a viable compromise I guess. The data is literally a list of tuples of this kind: `scored_items = [('14',534.9),('4',86.0),('78',543.21),('76',3543.9),....]`. I.e. object_id and score pairs.

Comment: Is there always a valid set? I mean a set of 20 objects with weights above T?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes by definition because we know that the top 20 have a sum of scores = t*4

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting question but if you look at the paper being cited (http://procaccia.info/papers/sumofus.tark11.pdf), that's not the algorithm they're using to get the strategyproof guarantee.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Check out **Theorem 2.5** here http://www.arpitaghosh.com/papers/games_hcomp.pdf. Or essentially, just read footnote `18` on page 11 of this same link.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: what made you say they're using a different one?

Comment: AFPT11 refers to the paper I linked to above. The mechanism is to divide the participants into two random groups, then have each group rate the other and take the top k/2 in each (discarding intra-group ratings) so that no participant will be negatively affected by their ratings.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: You're right about that. Peculiar how it's been interpreted in arpitaghosh.com/papers/games_hcomp.pdf. Specifically, I'm referring to how `footnote 18` surmises Theorem 2.5 on page 11. It's veritably a different mechanism. And this paper is by Dr. Arpita Ghosh. a highly reputable researcher on the topic. Maybe both interpretations converge somehow? It's a mind bender.

Comment: The footnote is just defining what it means to be 1/4-competitive (4-competitive? People disagree on whether to use the numerator or denominator for approximation ratios). "Randomized" doesn't mean "uniformly at random", which is the premise for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of what I mentioned in the comments.

Since we want items such that the sum of the scores is large, we can weight the choice so that we are more likely to pick samples with large scores.

```
import numpy as np
import math

def normalize(p):
    return p/sum(p)

def get_sample(scored_items, N=20, max_iter = 1000):
    topN = sorted(scored_items, key=lambda k: k[1],reverse = True)[:N]
    T = sum(n for _, n in topN)
    t = math.ceil(T/4)
    i = 0
    scores = np.array([x[1] for x in scored_items])
    p=normalize(scores)
    while i < max_iter:
        sample_indexes = np.random.choice(a=range(len(ids)), size=N, replace=False, p=p)
        sample = [scored_items[x] for x in sample_indexes]
        if sum(n for _, n in sample) >= t:
            print("Found a solution at iteration %d"%i)
            return sample
        i+=1
    print("Could not find a solution after %d iterations"%max_iter)
    return None
```

An example of how to use it:

```
np.random.seed(0)
ids = range(1000)
scores = 10000*np.random.random_sample(size=len(ids))
scored_items = list(zip(map(str, ids), scores))

sample = get_sample(scored_items, 20)
#Found a solution at iteration 0
print(sum(n for _, n in sample))
#139727.1229832652
```

Though this is not guaranteed to get a solution, I ran this in a loop 100 times and each time a distinct solution was found on the first iteration.

Comment: Ah, `p/sum(p)` normalization is the key.

Comment: @HassanBaig yes the `p` has to sum to 1. I actually had a typo in the code I initially posted, but it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do not know of a efficient way for huge lists something like this works even for 1000 or so items. You can do a bit better if you don't need *True* randomness

```
import random 

testList = [x for x in range(1,1000)]
T = sum(range(975, 1000))/4

while True:
    rs = random.sample(testList, 15)
    if sum(rs) >= t: break 

print rs
```

Comment: Alright. That's *a solution* I suppose. The `while True` is making me shudder.

Comment: @HassanBaig it's not guaranteed to be finite but if it takes to the end of the universe i'll buy you a drink

Comment: The universe is ending and you're buying me only 1 drink? Come on man, at least 2!